# Register Form - buging with verification

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Angular and ngIF for veryfi the inputs (lenght etc).
It is working but sometimes when you write in good way and go to next input it say that lenght must have min 5 char (when it have for ex 8). 
Why it is work one moment good, and other so bad?

For password error box :

```
   <div *ngIf="personpassword.errors && (personpassword.dirty || personpassword.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
      <div [hidden]="!personpassword.errors.required">
        <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <p>Hasło jest wymagane!</p>
      </div>
      <div [hidden]="!personpassword.errors.minlength">
        <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <p>Hasło musi mieć przynajmniej 6 znaków</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And the input:

```
<div class="inputs">
  <input type="password" name="phone" value="" [(ngModel)]="password" required minlength="6" #personpassword="ngModel">
</div>
```

All other inputs and error i write in the same way...

So what is the problem ? There is 11 inputs.

Comment: When I have had large forms with many input elements, I used copy/paste to copy the boilerplate part of the If and validation message logic and then update the template reference variable (#personpassword) and all of the references to that variable. Then I'd have a similar problem. In my case, the problem was that on a few of the elements I had copied the validation logic and not renamed every one of the template reference variable references. Is it possible that has happened here as well?

Comment: All  is renamed good. Prev i have this problem but its one week ago : /
The button who is disabled and going clickable (when all data is good) it unlock... But the errors up is showing : / I can just make that the error box will be cleaning after that. But i dont think its a good way ^^

Comment: Is there any way to create a plunker that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: you can go to eurobonus.pl/register
Some times its bugged sometimes not.